# Setting and accessing metafields on Shopify images

Tags: metadata, shopify

I am trying to use the image metafield functionality described in the Shopify API reference as such:

```
"{
"position":1,
"metafields":[
{"key":"variant_sku",
"value":"A176-6053",
"value_type":"string",
"namespace":"global"}
],
"src":"http://some.url/images/000/013/369/original/a176-6053.jpg?1337973636
}
```

When I pull up this product in Rails console I do not see the metafields (there is no metafields method for the image object), and I haven't had any luck referring to the metafields in the liquid template as such:

```
{{ image.metafields.global.variant_sku }}
```

I noticed that images are conspicuously absent from this list describing where metafields can be used: "You can store additional information about your products, variants, collections, orders, blogs, pages and you shop itself in metafields."

Yet there is an image example in the API reference. What am I missing?

My ultimate goal is to send the SKU along with the image via the API, and then to access this through liquid/javascript to support displaying the correct image for specific color/style variations.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: I actually noticed a hole in the API. You can set the 'alt' tag for images, but you cannot retrieve them - similar to the problem you have. Image 'alt' tags are saved as metafields, but if you query the metafield resource they seem to be non-existant

Comment: ...other than in the liquid templates, obviously. I found the way around this problem is to also save the label in the filename of the image, and then you can do a query for images of that product that contain the label in the filename

Answer (score 1):

Metafield need to be requested on their own for the resource, they are not embedded into the response by default. The API docs have examples of how to retrieve them.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing the 'alt' tag of the image is a metafield, why not set the SKU in the alt tag for the image.

You will be able to access the set value for the 'alt' tag via Shopify liquid - it is just you will not be able to retrieve the 'alt' tag via the ShopifyAPI.

This is my Rails example of saving an image that is submitted via an html form, and saving an 'alt' tag with it...

```
images = params[:images] || nil

if images
 images.each do |image|
      a = ShopifyAPI::Image.new
      a.prefix_options = {:product_id => params[:product_id]}
      a.metafields = [{:key => 'alt', :value => 'Cake', :value_type => "string", :namespace =>  "tags"}]
      a.attachment = Base64.encode64(image.read)
      a.filename = image.original_filename
      a.save
 end
else
.
.
.
```

Hope that helps.